# Defining the Complex Line Integral w.r.t. $x$ and $y$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Ahlfors defines line integrals with respect $x$ as follows:

$$
\int_\gamma f\ dx = {1 \over 2} \left( \int_\gamma f\ dz + \int_\gamma f\ \overline{dz} \right)
$$

From this I take it as obvious that $\int_\gamma f\ dx  \in \mathbb{R}$.  Similarly, Ahlfors defines $\int_\gamma f\ dy$ as follows:

$$
\int_\gamma f\ dy = {1 \over 2i} \left( \int_\gamma f\ dz - \int_\gamma f\ \overline{dz} \right)
$$

**Question:** What is the point of the "$i$" in the denominator of the definition of $\int_\gamma f\ dy$?  Is it to force $\int_\gamma f\ dy$ to be real?

Comment: $\int_\gamma f\,dx$ is in general not real unless $f$ is. Anyway, $dz = dx + idy$.

Comment: You mean $\int_\gamma f\ dz$ isn't in general real?  How could it not be the case that $\int_\gamma f\ dx \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If $f$ isn't real, why should $\int_\gamma f\,dx$ be real?

Comment: Let $w = \int_\gamma f\ dz$.  Then ${w + \overline{w} \over 2}  \in \mathbb{R}$ as Hayden below points out.  Yet ${w + \overline{w} \over 2} = \int_\gamma f\ dx$.

Comment: No, it's $$\int_\gamma f\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_\gamma f\,dz + \int_\gamma f\,\overline{dz}\right) = \int_\gamma f\,(dz + \overline{dz}),$$ not $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_\gamma f\,dz + \overline{\int_\gamma f\,dz}\right).$$

Comment: I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious, but Ahlfors seems to define $\int_\gamma f\ dx$ as precisely ${1 \over 2} \left( \int_\gamma f\ dz + \overline{\int_\gamma f\ dz}\right)$.  If you have the text, this is at the bottom of page 103 in the Third Edition.

Comment: I looked at another copy of the text in better shape than mine.  I didn't see the bar over the $f$.  I see now that $\int_\gamma \overline{dz} = \overline{\int_\gamma \overline{f} dz}$.  My mistake.

Comment: Having taken a look, I can see why you didn't see the bar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The definitions are based on the fact that $\Re(z)=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$ and $\Im(z)=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$.